# Thumbnail not show on related post blogger

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, blogger

I use blogger costum domain. Related post image thumbnail not show on the detail post ([example this post](https://www.perantiguru.com/2020/02/jadwal-pencairan-dana-bos.html)). Image was upload (cache) on my subdomain.

[image: like this]

this script on related post

```js
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var related_blogUrl = "https://www.perantiguru.com";
var related_total = 6;
var related_thumbnail = 1;
var related_imgWidth = 210;
var related_imgHeight = 130;
(function(){
var relatedNum = 0; var relatedUrl = new Array(); var relatedImage = new Array(); var relatedTitle = new Array(); var relatedTotal = related_total; var callback = "relatedposts"; var containerID = document.getElementById("relatedposts"); var noImg = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAADElEQVQImWOor68HAAL+AX7vOF2TAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"; var imgSize = [related_imgWidth, related_imgHeight]; window[callback] = function(data){ for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++){ var entry = data.feed.entry[i]; relatedTitle[relatedNum] = entry.title.$t; for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++){ if ("alternate" == entry.link[j].rel){ relatedUrl[relatedNum] = entry.link[j].href; break; } } relatedImage[relatedNum] = noImg.replace("/s72-c/", "/w" + imgSize[0] + "-h" + imgSize[1] + "-p-k-no-nu/"); if ("media$thumbnail" in entry) { relatedImage[relatedNum] = entry.media$thumbnail.url.replace("/s72-c/", "/w"+imgSize[0]+"-h"+imgSize[1]+"-p-k-no-nu/"); } relatedNum++; } }; function filterTags(g, h) { var e = g.split("<"); for (var f = 0; f < e.length; f++) { if (e[f].indexOf(">") != -1) { e[f] = e[f].substring(e[f].indexOf(">") + 1, e[f].length) } } e = e.join(""); e = e.substring(0, h - 1); return e; }; function contains(a, e) { for (var f = 0; f < a.length; f++) { if (a[f] == e) return true; } return false; }; function removeDuplicates() { var v = new Array(0); var A = new Array(0); var w = new Array(0); for (var u = 0; u < relatedUrl.length; u++) { if (!contains(v, relatedUrl[u])) { v.length += 1; v[v.length - 1] = relatedUrl[u]; A.length += 1; A[A.length - 1] = relatedImage[u]; w.length += 1; w[w.length - 1] = relatedTitle[u]; } } relatedUrl = v; relatedImage = A; relatedTitle = w; }; function createRelated() { removeDuplicates(); for (var u = 0; u < relatedTitle.length; u++) { var B = Math.floor((relatedTitle.length - 1) * Math.random()); var s = relatedUrl[u]; var C = relatedImage[u]; var i = relatedTitle[u]; relatedUrl[u] = relatedUrl[B]; relatedImage[u] = relatedImage[B]; relatedTitle[u] = relatedTitle[B]; relatedUrl[B] = s; relatedImage[B] = C; relatedTitle[B] = i; } var r = 0; var D = Math.floor((relatedTitle.length - 1) * Math.random()); var z = D; var t = document.URL; var e = ""; while (r < relatedTotal) { if (relatedUrl[D] != t) { e += "<li>"; if (related_thumbnail >= 1) { e += "<div class='thumbnail'>"; e += "<a href='" + relatedUrl[D] + "' title='" + relatedTitle[D] + "'>"; e += "<img src='" + relatedImage[D] + "' alt='" + relatedTitle[D] + "' width='" + imgSize[0] +"' height='" + imgSize[1] + "'/>"; e += "</a>"; e += "</div>"; } e += "<div class='title'>"; e += "<a href='" + relatedUrl[D] + "' title='" + relatedTitle[D] + "'>" + relatedTitle[D] + "</a>"; e += "</div>"; e += "</li>"; r++; if (r == relatedTotal) { break; } } if (D < relatedTitle.length - 1) { D++; } else { D = 0; } if (D == z) { break; } } containerID.innerHTML = e; }; var labels = ""; var ralatedlist = document.querySelectorAll("span.list-item"); ralatedlist.forEach(function(list) { labels += 'label:"' + list.dataset.label + '"|'; }); var js = document.createElement("script"); var blogUrl = related_blogUrl.replace(/\/$/, ""); js.src = blogUrl + "/feeds/posts/summary?v=2&q=" + labels + "&alt=json&callback=" + callback + "&max-results=20"; js.onload = createRelated; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
})();
//]]>
</script>
```

help me to fix it

Comment: there's no problem on your website. everything is fine.

Comment: i mean, related post thumb not show from external source..  can fix it with edit java script?

Comment: thank you,, the problem is fix now

Answer (score 2):

fixed, **Thumbnail not show on related post blogger from external source**

**Before:**

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div class='relatedposts'>
<h4>Post Lainnya</h4>
<ul id='relatedposts'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<span class='list-item' expr:data-label='data:label.name'/>
</b:loop>
</ul>
</div>
</b:if>
```

```js
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var related_blogUrl = "https://www.perantiguru.com";
var related_total = 6;
var related_thumbnail = 1;
var related_imgWidth = 210;
var related_imgHeight = 130;
(function(){
var relatedNum = 0; var relatedUrl = new Array(); var relatedImage = new Array(); var relatedTitle = new Array(); var relatedTotal = related_total; var callback = "relatedposts"; var containerID = document.getElementById("relatedposts"); var noImg = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAADElEQVQImWOor68HAAL+AX7vOF2TAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"; var imgSize = [related_imgWidth, related_imgHeight]; window[callback] = function(data){ for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++){ var entry = data.feed.entry[i]; relatedTitle[relatedNum] = entry.title.$t; for (var j = 0; j < entry.link.length; j++){ if ("alternate" == entry.link[j].rel){ relatedUrl[relatedNum] = entry.link[j].href; break; } } relatedImage[relatedNum] = noImg.replace("/s72-c/", "/w" + imgSize[0] + "-h" + imgSize[1] + "-p-k-no-nu/"); if ("media$thumbnail" in entry) { relatedImage[relatedNum] = entry.media$thumbnail.url.replace("/s72-c/", "/w"+imgSize[0]+"-h"+imgSize[1]+"-p-k-no-nu/"); } relatedNum++; } }; function filterTags(g, h) { var e = g.split("<"); for (var f = 0; f < e.length; f++) { if (e[f].indexOf(">") != -1) { e[f] = e[f].substring(e[f].indexOf(">") + 1, e[f].length) } } e = e.join(""); e = e.substring(0, h - 1); return e; }; function contains(a, e) { for (var f = 0; f < a.length; f++) { if (a[f] == e) return true; } return false; }; function removeDuplicates() { var v = new Array(0); var A = new Array(0); var w = new Array(0); for (var u = 0; u < relatedUrl.length; u++) { if (!contains(v, relatedUrl[u])) { v.length += 1; v[v.length - 1] = relatedUrl[u]; A.length += 1; A[A.length - 1] = relatedImage[u]; w.length += 1; w[w.length - 1] = relatedTitle[u]; } } relatedUrl = v; relatedImage = A; relatedTitle = w; }; function createRelated() { removeDuplicates(); for (var u = 0; u < relatedTitle.length; u++) { var B = Math.floor((relatedTitle.length - 1) * Math.random()); var s = relatedUrl[u]; var C = relatedImage[u]; var i = relatedTitle[u]; relatedUrl[u] = relatedUrl[B]; relatedImage[u] = relatedImage[B]; relatedTitle[u] = relatedTitle[B]; relatedUrl[B] = s; relatedImage[B] = C; relatedTitle[B] = i; } var r = 0; var D = Math.floor((relatedTitle.length - 1) * Math.random()); var z = D; var t = document.URL; var e = ""; while (r < relatedTotal) { if (relatedUrl[D] != t) { e += "<li>"; if (related_thumbnail >= 1) { e += "<div class='thumbnail'>"; e += "<a href='" + relatedUrl[D] + "' title='" + relatedTitle[D] + "'>"; e += "<img src='" + relatedImage[D] + "' alt='" + relatedTitle[D] + "' width='" + imgSize[0] +"' height='" + imgSize[1] + "'/>"; e += "</a>"; e += "</div>"; } e += "<div class='title'>"; e += "<a href='" + relatedUrl[D] + "' title='" + relatedTitle[D] + "'>" + relatedTitle[D] + "</a>"; e += "</div>"; e += "</li>"; r++; if (r == relatedTotal) { break; } } if (D < relatedTitle.length - 1) { D++; } else { D = 0; } if (D == z) { break; } } containerID.innerHTML = e; }; var labels = ""; var ralatedlist = document.querySelectorAll("span.list-item"); ralatedlist.forEach(function(list) { labels += 'label:"' + list.dataset.label + '"|'; }); var js = document.createElement("script"); var blogUrl = related_blogUrl.replace(/\/$/, ""); js.src = blogUrl + "/feeds/posts/summary?v=2&q=" + labels + "&alt=json&callback=" + callback + "&max-results=20"; js.onload = createRelated; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
})();
//]]>
</script>
```

**After:**

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div id='related-posts'>
<b:loop index='labelcount' values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<script>
  var currentURL = &#39;<data:blog.url/>&#39;;
</script>
<b:if cond='data:labelcount &lt; 1'>
<script async='async' expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=display_related_posts&quot;' type='text/javascript'/></b:if></b:loop>
</div><div style='clear:both'/>
</b:if>
```

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
/*<![CDATA[*/
var post_thumbnail_width = 180;
var post_thumbnail_height = 120;
var max_related_entries = 6;

function escapeRegExp(string){return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,"\\$&")}function replaceAll(str,term,replacement){return str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(term),"g"),replacement)}function display_related_posts(json_feed){for(var defaultnoimage="https://i.ibb.co/yS6JvBh/no-image.jpg",post_titles=new Array,title_num=0,post_urls=new Array,post_thumbnail_url=new Array,relatedpoststitle=(window.location.href,"Post Lainnya"),border_color="#DDDDDD",i=0;i<json_feed.feed.entry.length;i++){var feed_entry=json_feed.feed.entry[i];post_titles[title_num]=feed_entry.title.$t;try{post_thumbnail_url[title_num]=feed_entry.media$thumbnail.url}catch(error){s=feed_entry.content.$t,a=s.indexOf("<img"),b=s.indexOf('src="',a),c=s.indexOf('"',b+5),d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-5),-1!=a&&-1!=b&&-1!=c&&""!=d?post_thumbnail_url[title_num]=d:"undefined"!=typeof defaultnoimage?post_thumbnail_url[title_num]=defaultnoimage:post_thumbnail_url[title_num]="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAADElEQVQImWOor68HAAL+AX7vOF2TAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"}for(var k=0;k<feed_entry.link.length;k++)"alternate"==feed_entry.link[k].rel&&(post_urls[title_num]=feed_entry.link[k].href,title_num++)}var random_entry=Math.floor((post_titles.length-1)*Math.random()),iteration=0;if(post_titles.length>0){var rp_heading=document.createElement("h2"),textnode=document.createTextNode(relatedpoststitle);rp_heading.appendChild(textnode),document.getElementById("related-posts").appendChild(rp_heading);var rp_container=document.createElement("div");rp_container.setAttribute("style","clear: both;"),rp_container.setAttribute("id","rp-container"),document.getElementById("related-posts").appendChild(rp_container)}for(;iteration<post_titles.length&&20>iteration&&max_related_entries>iteration;)if(post_urls[random_entry]!=currentURL){var rp_anchor=document.createElement("a");0!=iteration?rp_anchor.setAttribute("style","text-decoration:none;padding:10px;float:left;border-left: none "+border_color+";"):rp_anchor.setAttribute("style","text-decoration:none;padding:10px;float:left;"),rp_anchor.setAttribute("id","rp-anchor-"+iteration),rp_anchor.setAttribute("href",post_urls[random_entry]),document.getElementById("rp-container").appendChild(rp_anchor);var rp_img=document.createElement("img");rp_img.setAttribute("style","width:"+post_thumbnail_width+"px;height:"+post_thumbnail_height+"px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;"),rp_img.setAttribute("id","rp-img-"+iteration);var pin=String(post_thumbnail_url[random_entry].match(/\/s72-c\//));post_thumbnail_url[random_entry]=replaceAll(post_thumbnail_url[random_entry],pin,"/w"+post_thumbnail_width+"-h"+post_thumbnail_height+"-p/"),rp_img.setAttribute("src",post_thumbnail_url[random_entry]),rp_img.setAttribute("alt","Matched post excerpt thumbnail in the post footer."),document.getElementById("rp-anchor-"+iteration).appendChild(rp_img);var rp_para=document.createElement("div");rp_para.setAttribute("style","width:"+post_thumbnail_width+"px; height:"+post_thumbnail_height+"px;border: 0pt none ; margin: auto; padding-top: 18px; line-height:1.6;"),rp_para.setAttribute("id","rp-para-"+iteration);var textnode=document.createTextNode(post_titles[random_entry]);rp_para.appendChild(textnode),document.getElementById("rp-anchor-"+iteration).appendChild(rp_para),iteration++,random_entry<post_titles.length-1?random_entry++:random_entry=0}else iteration++,random_entry<post_titles.length-1?random_entry++:random_entry=0;post_urls.splice(0,post_urls.length),post_thumbnail_url.splice(0,post_thumbnail_url.length),post_titles.splice(0,post_titles.length)}
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Thankyou , i was looking for something like this to solve my thumbnail problem.