# fixing external source image display in blogger related posts

Tags: javascript, xml, blogger

hi as title suggests that how do i fix displaying external source image in blogger using javascript here is the code i am using blogger xml.

```
<div class='relatedPosts'>
      <div id='relatedPosts'>
        <script>
          var labelArray = [<b:if cond='data:post.labels'><b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>&quot;<data:label.name/>&quot;<b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>,</b:if></b:loop></b:if>];
          var relatedPostConfig = {
            homePage: &quot;<data:blog.homepageUrl.canonical/>&quot;,
            widgetTitle: &quot;<h3 class='title'><data:messages.youMayLikeThesePosts/></h3>&quot;,
            numPosts: 3,
            summaryLength: 20,
            titleLength:&quot;auto&quot;,
            thumbnailSize: 260,
            noImage: &quot;data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=&quot;,
            containerId: &quot;relatedPosts&quot;,
            newTabLink: false,
            moreText: &quot;Read more&quot;,
            widgetStyle: 2,
            callBack:function(){}
          }
        </script>
```

another javascript to use css dynamic and other displaying data

```
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/ var randomRelatedIndex,showRelatedPost;(function(n,m,k){var d={widgetTitle:"<h3 class='title'>Related Posts</h3>",widgetStyle:1,homePage:"http://www.jagodesain.com",numPosts:7,summaryLength:320,titleLength:"auto",thumbnailSize:200,noImage:"data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=",containerId:"related-posts",newTabLink:false,moreText:"Read more",callBack:function(){}}; for(var f in relatedPostConfig){d[f]=(relatedPostConfig[f]=="undefined")?d[f]:relatedPostConfig[f]}var j=function(a){var b=m.createElement("script");b.async="async";b.rel="preload";b.src=a;k.appendChild(b)},o=function(b,a){return Math.floor(Math.random()*(a-b+1))+b},l=function(a){var p=a.length,c,b;if(p===0){return false}while(--p){c=Math.floor(Math.random()*(p+1));b=a[p];a[p]=a[c];a[c]=b}return a},e=(typeof labelArray=="object"&&labelArray.length>0)?"/-/"+l(labelArray)[0]:"",h=function(b){var c=b.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t-d.numPosts,a=o(1,(c>0?c:1));j(d.homePage.replace(/\/$/,"")+"/feeds/posts/summary"+e+"?alt=json-in-script&orderby=updated&start-index="+a+"&max-results="+d.numPosts+"&callback=showRelatedPost")},g=function(z){var s=document.getElementById(d.containerId),x=l(z.feed.entry),A=d.widgetStyle,c=d.widgetTitle+'<ul class="related style-'+A+'">',b=d.newTabLink?' target="_blank"':"",y='<!-- <div class="clear"/> -->',v,t,w,r,u;if(!s){return}for(var q=0;q<d.numPosts;q++){if(q==x.length){break}t=x[q].title.$t;w=(d.titleLength!=="auto"&&d.titleLength<t.length)?t.substring(0,d.titleLength)+"&hellip;":t; r=("media$thumbnail"in x[q]&&d.thumbnailSize!==false)?x[q].media$thumbnail.url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g , "//").replace(/\/s[0-9]+(\-c)?/, "/s"+d.thumbnailSize):d.noImage;u=("summary"in x[q]&&d.summaryLength>0)?x[q].summary.$t.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g," ").replace(/<.*?>/g,"").replace(/[<>]/g,"").substring(0,d.summaryLength)+"&hellip;":"";for(var p=0,a=x[q].link.length;p<a;p++){v=(x[q].link[p].rel=="alternate")?x[q].link[p].href:"#"} if(A==2){c+='<li><div class="item"><div class="itemThumbnail"><a aria-label="'+w+'" href="'+v+'"><div class="lazy" data-bg="'+r+'"></div></a></div><div class="itemTitle"><a href="'+v+'"><span>'+w+'</span></a></div></div></li>'} else{c+='<li><div class="item"><div class="itemThumbnail"><a aria-label="'+w+'" href="'+v+'"><div class="lazy" data-bg="'+r+'"></div></a></div><div class="itemTitle"><a href="'+v+'"><span>'+w+'</span></a></div></div></li>'} }s.innerHTML=c+="</ul>";d.callBack()};randomRelatedIndex=h;showRelatedPost=g;j(d.homePage.replace(/\/$/,"")+"/feeds/posts/summary"+e+"?alt=json-in-script&orderby=updated&max-results=0&callback=randomRelatedIndex")})(window,document,document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]); /*]]>*/</script>
```

as per my knowledge i have to add the feed rss url to fetch data like this

```
<script async='async' expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=display_related_posts&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
```

i am not too much knowledgeable about javascript, how do i add feeds url like this above in code in way that images from external source also displayed. [example url is here](https://aretheres.blogspot.com/2022/08/panasonic-lumix-gh5-4k-digital-camera.html)

Comment: Can you add a snippet to your question that reproduces the problem?

Comment: related answer is here but its not same css https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389111/thumbnail-not-show-on-related-post-blogger

Comment: here is a github repo that provides a widget that allows you to show popular posts https://github.com/j3soon/Blogger-Widgets/blob/master/PopularPostsWidget.html

Answer (score 0):

IT will be done if you try finding the source code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).